# How to write a BIGQuery query to get a list of some words and check if they contain in another String?

Tags: google-bigquery, subquery

I need to get some content with the words containing from wordlist I have tried following but not getting exact results.

`` SELECT q.id, q.title from `questions`q JOIN `words` ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(q.title,word) limit 50 ``

Data Words:[Mango, Tire, web, gray, Apple]

expected Questions from the database: 
1. What web browser do you prefer? 
2. Do you have gray hairs?
3. Which is your fav Mango or apple

Comment: more details needed. provide example of data and expected output.

Comment: have you tried anything? present what you tried and why it "not getting exact results."?

Comment: SELECT q.id, q.title from `questions`q JOIN `words` ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(q.title,word) limit 50. I have tried this query and it didnt return anything.

Comment: how your words are presented  - is it just string with comma separated words or table with those words one per row or somethingelse?

Comment: In Table one word per row. So I can Pull those from subquery too but dont know how to loop them through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.questions` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, "What web browser do you prefer?" title UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, "Do you have gray hairs?" UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, "Which is your fav Mango or apple?" UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, "How to write a BIGQuery query to get a list of some words and check if they contain in another String?" UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, "Is there any free way to search github that isn't severely limited and simple (aka: searching for special characters or using regex)?" UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, "Is there any way to run a portion of a large query on bigquery when the free quota doesn't allow it?" UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, "How to unpivot in BigQuery?" UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, "how get rows with latest date?" UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, "Have you heard of weblogic?"
), `project.dataset.words` AS (
  SELECT 'Mango' word UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tire' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'web' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'gray' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BigQuery'
)
SELECT DISTINCT q.id, q.title 
FROM `project.dataset.questions` q 
JOIN `project.dataset.words` 
ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(q.title), r'\b' || LOWER(word) || r'\b') 
LIMIT 50
```

with output

```
Row id  title    
1   1   What web browser do you prefer?  
2   2   Do you have gray hairs?  
3   3   Which is your fav Mango or apple?    
4   4   How to write a BIGQuery query to get a list of some words and check if they contain in another String?   
5   6   Is there any way to run a portion of a large query on bigquery when the free quota doesn't allow it?     
6   7   How to unpivot in BigQuery?
```

To run it agains your own data - just remove TCE (WITH statements) and use your real tables references

Comment: Thank you Mikhail This one works but IT gives me all words that has the word in it. e.g  "Have you heard of **weblogic**?" which has web keyword in it. I want strict word filter.

Comment: please clarify! what you mean by strict in this case

Comment: Means I want the questions to be returned with the Words only questions. not one with concatenated with other letters around them.  e.g I dont want these type of questions where the word web is in weblogic.  e.g "Have you heard of weblogic?"  I want questions to come out only with word "web" in it.